# Parallel.For vs for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, parallel.for

I am wrapping my head around running paralleling threads, so I decided to test it out on a smaller basis and then expand when I am comfortable.  I am pitting the same process against itself; one using Parallel.For and the other using a basic for loop.  I am capturing the time (in ticks) for the comparison.  The example code takes an array (in this case 53 two character strings) and fills a given `ListBox` with the array.

What makes little to no sense to me is that when I run the basic For loop, it results in an average of 1,400 ticks, but when I run the `Parallel.For` loop it returns  5,200 ticks on average.  Is the sample size too small for the parallel to be effective?

Here are the two snippets I am using.  The `Parallel.For` loop is:

```
public void ListboxFromArray(ListBox listbox, string[] array1)
{
    // This method takes an array and fills a listbox full of items from the array
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();

    Parallel.For(0, array1.Count(),
    index =>
    {
        listbox.Items.Add(array1[index]);
    });
    stopWatch.Stop();
    long ts = stopWatch.ElapsedTicks;
    string elapsedTime = ts.ToString() + " Ticks"; ;
    MessageBox.Show(elapsedTime);

}
```

and the `for` loop is:

```
public void ListboxFromArray(ListBox listbox, string[] array1)
{
    // This method takes an array and fills a listbox full of items from the array
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Count(); i++)
    {
        listbox.Items.Add(array1[i]);
    }
    stopWatch.Stop();
    long ts = stopWatch.ElapsedTicks;
    string elapsedTime = ts.ToString() + " Ticks"; ;
    MessageBox.Show(elapsedTime);
}
```

Thank you for any input or validation of my thoughts in advance.

Comment: In addition to the execution time, you might want to look over what the final order of the listbox's items are. Best case scenario is that they'll be in a random semi-mismatched order irrelevant to the array. Worst case is that if the listbox isn't thread safe, it'll be doing undefined things. In addition to only using for high-CPU cases, you should try to reserve Parallel for when item execution doesn't all depend on one central object. (This may mean merging together results in the future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your sample size is way too small, and the work you are doing within the loop is far too small to overcome the overhead of the task/thread management. There is little point in paraleling a in-memory op that consumes so little CPU. If you were doing a 100,000 item sort then maybe...

Comment: Thanks, that's what's nagging me then.  I wasn't 100% sure, but that makes that is what makes the most sense to me too, I just wanted a second opinion.

Comment: Actually this is wrong. His sample size is not too small - his code is not thread safe on top of it. Plus it i manipulating a UI control which is not doable multi threaded, so if it works it works by automatically marshalling it to ONE thread. Totally borked test.

Comment: @TomTom - the Items is simply a ListBoxObjectCollection which is not thread safe (no collections are unless explicitly designed to be so) but that doesnt affect the performance of his test. Agreed that the outcome of the Add might not be in any defined order (but thats expected from Parallel.For) and this is not a real-world example, but since he's not getting an exception, his access to the collection is permitted - unless you think that Parallel.ForEach is "noticing" the cross thread access to the control and then single threading .... which I dont think is likely. A Poor test, but ...

Answer (score 2):

Using `Parallel.For` is useful if you want to compute for each item in the collection something that takes some time amount of time to compute.

```
int[] coll = new int[]{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};

Parallel.ForEach(coll,
    item=>
    {
       Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(item));
       Console.WriteLine(item + "Finished");
    });
```

compared to the sequential way

```
foreach (var item in coll)
{
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(item));
    Console.WriteLine(item + "Finished");
}
```

the first code runs faster, because it really does the work in parallel.

In your case, if you just want to perform just "no work" then the overhead in `thead` is just to big.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that....first, you're accessing a UI control (ListBox) from a non-UI thread. AFAIK, `Parallel.For` doesn't do any thread marshalling to make that safe. Second, you're accessing the same collection (`ListBox.Items`) from multiple threads without locking - again, not safe.

In general, I'd say this is *not* what `Parallel.For` is designed for. You're not exactly bottlenecking on I/O or CPU here, which means any parallelism overhead is going to dwarf any conceivable improvement.

Comment: I don't actually disagree with you on the uses, I was more asking for my own edification on my understanding of the processes involved in each vs the other.  Thank you.